# Detect incoming VoIP call Android

Tags: java, android, voip

I want to close my app, when user get Viber/Skype/WhatsApp call. I am tried to use AudioFocus listener and Notification parsing, both of them not really good. May be there is other method that can help me?

Comment: please elaborate on what you tried and what problems you faced.

Comment: When i tried to parse notifications i got a problem that only way to use it, it is manually check all type of notifications form all VoIP applications, find difference between data inside notifications of text messages/pics/smiles and data inside incoming calls notifications, and then send intent to my app for close. This will work until first change of notification data of current VoIP application.(Who knows how frequently Viber/Skype/WhatsApp updates this part of code);

Comment: This is does not work too : AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         int result=  am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to make it? I am facing the same challenge, too...

Comment: did you have any luck guys?

Comment: @ShimonShnitzer is there anything that we can do?

Answer (score 5):

Checking for MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION in audio manager should achieve this. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

```
public static boolean isVoip(Context context){
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION){
         return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```