# How to detect internet call, voip call, WhatsApp, Skype etc.. on Android?

Tags: android, call, voip, whatsapp, skype

The similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566879/detect-incoming-voip-call-android) but no answers yet..